# How do I turn off "Snap to grid" in Word 365?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I am trying to draw an arrow from top to bottom in Word, but it never draws straight as I want it to, and it looks like it keeps snapping to some kind of invisible grid. I followed the directions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/snap-charts-pictures-and-objects-to-a-grid-to-align-them-in-word-d9c687fc-926e-4eca-8cef-952eed714012), and it is still snapping to grid.

How can I permanently turn this feature off?

Comment: Is the problem with text frames? or what do you mean by "draw an array"?

Comment: @harrymc sorry I meant draw an arrow

Comment: This was a bug introduced in Word 2013 that I thought had been fixed. If you initially draw the arrow at 90 or 180 degrees, you can do it, but you cannot move it to exactly vertical or horizontal. **I am seeing the same thing.** Try holding down the Shift key when you initially draw it.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I've tried shift, alt, ctrl but neither work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading your question, perhaps incorrectly, that you cannot draw a vertical line or arrow in Word. Specifically, if you try to move it to vertical you cannot do this. If my reading is correct, This is a bug in Word that has been present since Word 2013. You can workaround it in the Shape Format tab by setting the height of a horizontal line to 0 or the width of a vertical line to 0.

[image: screenshot from Shape Format tab]

In the screenshot above, changing the .05 to 0 produces a horizontal line.

See also: [Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's answer in the Microsoft Answers Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/drawing-a-horizontal-line/2598f0b2-ec7b-415e-91bc-8bc75a644af2?LastReply=true#LastReply) some time ago.

---

Alternatively, try this setting. You get to this dialog on the Shape Format tab under Alignment > Grid Settings.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have tried the thing on your 2nd picture but it didn't work. I will try the first one when get a chance.

Comment: Was my assumption or guess about what you were asking correct? If so, the first picture should do it.

Comment: I am going to insert shapes and clicking on arrow, then clicking and dragging vertically

Comment: Did you try the method of setting to 0?

Comment: Sorry not yet I will only be able to get to it after the weekend

Comment: Method of setting to 0 works, but every time I try to click and drag it, it snaps again, so after every click and drag, I have to manually set width to 0. Pretty annoying but seems to work.

Comment: Upvoting and accepting because this seems to be the best workaround available at the moment

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut to open the "Shape format" tab once I click on the arrow?

Comment: Once you click on (select) an Arrow, the Shape Format tab has the focus. If you press the Alt key, you will see shortcuts for each of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correctly turned off snap in Drawing Options, but it's still
snapping, this might be a bug and you need to signal it to Microsoft
in the Feedback Hub.

While I don't know of a fix, I can offer a couple of workarounds :

1. Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key when adjusting the positioning,
   to override the snap
2. Right-click on the drawing object and select Properties and set the position manually.

Comment: The 'alt' method didn't work. Right click menu does not have a "properties" option. There are "format shape" and "more layout options..." but I can't find anything relevant in them, or at least I can't find the options to manually set the exact position of the arrow. I think I remember seeing the "properties" option and some dialog box about manual positioning in older versions of word, but I am not even sure about that at this point

Comment: This whole seems to have become a big mess in Word 365. Are you in Print Layout, and does snapping happen when you are not?

Comment: Yes I think I am in print layout mode (there a small icon in the bottom bar which looks like it's "selected"; hovering over it shows "print layout"). I haven't really checked any other mode, but I will have a look when I can.

Comment: Checking back on it, the options available to me are Read mode (uneditable), print layout (snapping problem) and web layout (snapping problem and the formatting is all messed up).